# Is it possible to use fire-and-forget WCF service action using no generated proxy/client

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asynchronous, fire-and-forget

**Prerequisites**

- **service project type**: .net 3.5 Class Library
- **service host**: IIS 7.5 / ASP.NET Compatibility mode is **on**

The single action defined for the service `DocumentsService` is `UploadDocument(Stream stream)`, accessible via HTTP (**webHttp binding**).

I've tried to decorate it with `[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]`.

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate="upload", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
void UploadDocument(System.IO.Stream stream);
```

Additionally I commented out the lines:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

as I thought it would be useless, as service would itself set 200 status given all is ok.

I don't use any generated **WCF** clients for the service. I use plain **ajax** request to submit the file.

**Problem**

This isn't a fire-and-forget request. It's sync and blocking. 
How can I have real fire-and-forget action? Can I use it without any **c#** proxy client?

**Edit**

1. I can't use `Task` class - I'm bound to .net framework 3.5.
2. Well, I have two parts: **uploading itself** and **post-processing**. How do I then chain this parts or instantiate async **post-processing** when file is uploaded?

Comment: Uploading data is *not* a fire-and-forget operation. You have to keep sending data until the upload completes. You are *not* making a single POST request and ignore the response.

Comment: @lexeme, Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use a worker thread from the thread-pool to send the request?

Example:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => UploadDocument(my_stream));
```

For .NET 3.5, you can access the thread pool directly, like this:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => UploadDocument(my_stream));
```

If you want to do something after the upload is complete, do the following:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
{
    UploadDocument(my_stream);

    DoSomePostProcessing();
});
```

Since `UploadDocument` is a synchronous method, `DoSomePostProcessing` will run after `UploadDocument` is complete. `DoSomePostProcessing` in this case will also run in a background thread.